# How does matlab compare two complex numbers?

Tags: matlab

I saw a file in matlab with used max() on a matrix whose entries are complex numbers. I can't understand how does matlab compare two complex numbers?

```
   ls1=max(tfsp');
```

Here , tfsp contains complex numbers.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  Can you give an example where you think Matlab is wrong?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation for `max`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html.

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation

Comment: Actually, reading the documentation @OliCharlesworth linked to,complex numbers are only mentioned under "tips" which you have to click to see.

Comment: (Though `help max` in R2010a does show the relevant passage.)

Comment: My mistake for not seeing the documentation and I think punished for it also. Thanks Li-aung for answering though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complex numbers are compared first by magnitude, then by phase angle (if there is a tie for the maximum magnitude.)

From `help max`:

```
When X is complex, the maximum is computed using the magnitude
MAX(ABS(X)). In the case of equal magnitude elements, then the phase
angle MAX(ANGLE(X)) is used.

NaN's are ignored when computing the maximum. When all elements in X
are NaN's, then the first one is returned as the maximum.
```